# Is there any way to rollback `dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent rollback`

Tags: networking, server, dpkg, iptables

In a very-not-my-best moment, I was trying to configure a laptop following some documentation. I followed the instructions in the documentation:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.132.111:5000
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.132.111:5000
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9091 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.132.111:9091
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

However, I realized too late that I was doing this in a terminal ssh'd into a different computer (not locally as I had intended). The computer can no longer connect to the internet even when plugged into ethernet (ping google.com doesn't work) - I can only connect to it through its hotspot. Is there any way to rollback the configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would think the -F command I seen in the summary of the first hit would do what you want.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=delete+all+iptables+rules

Comment: I don't necessarily want to flush all rules. I want to rollback to the existing configuration that existed.